# meminfo values does not add up

Tags: linux, memory

I am investigating a memory issue of in my system.  The following is `/proc/meminfo`:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       32869176 kB
MemFree:         1495144 kB
Buffers:           15052 kB
Cached:           123904 kB
SwapCached:        37404 kB
Active:          1411400 kB
Inactive:         759904 kB
Active(anon):    1369796 kB
Inactive(anon):   663364 kB
Active(file):      41604 kB
Inactive(file):    96540 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      64802808 kB
SwapFree:       64083052 kB
Dirty:               164 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1264272 kB
Mapped:            23940 kB
Shmem:               656 kB
Slab:             508344 kB
SReclaimable:      35888 kB
SUnreclaim:       472456 kB
KernelStack:        2952 kB
PageTables:        16256 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    81237396 kB
Committed_AS:    3424480 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      557636 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359169020 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     28672 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:    32502180 kB
DirectMap2M:      972800 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Adding up MemFree all the way to Inactive(file) would amount to about 10% of the MemTotal.  Free shows most of my RAM is used:

```
$ free -t
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      32869176   31403960    1465216          0      23504     135372
-/+ buffers/cache:   31245084    1624092
Swap:     64802808     719692   64083116
Total:    97671984   32123652   65548332
```

But the top 10 RSS processes are no where near enough:

```
$ grep VmRSS /proc/*/status | sort -k2 -h | tail -n 10
/proc/26526/status:VmRSS:           9272 kB
/proc/30731/status:VmRSS:          10772 kB
/proc/27143/status:VmRSS:          29816 kB
/proc/25802/status:VmRSS:          31156 kB
/proc/20750/status:VmRSS:          38972 kB
/proc/15231/status:VmRSS:          40932 kB
/proc/25511/status:VmRSS:          62140 kB
/proc/25519/status:VmRSS:         116836 kB
/proc/1747/status:VmRSS:          277516 kB
/proc/24658/status:VmRSS:         648960 kB
```

where did my RAM go?

Comment: This is long gone of course but did you try to total up _all_ of the VmRSS sizes?  Maybe there was a large number of smaller processes?  I did something like: `grep VmRSS /proc/[0-9]*/status | cut -f3 -d: | cut -c1-10 | ( echo '0' ; perl -n -e 'print "$_+";' ; echo "p" ) | dc `